# stop html button displaying below each other once screen size changes

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML for displaying buttons:

```
<td>
 <button id="inbox_button" class="HeaderButton">&#9993; (<?php echo $messages_num; ?>)</button>
 <!--
 <button id="monthly_cost_calculator_button"  class="HeaderButton">Calculator</button>
 <button id="remote_support_button"  class="HeaderButton" onclick="RemoteSupport();">Remote Support</button>
  -->
 <button id="customer_communication_button"  class="HeaderButton" onclick="AddCustomerCommunication();">Customer Communication</button>
 <button id="price_list_button" class="HeaderButton" onclick="PriceList();">Price List</button>
</td>
```

but as the screen gets smaller, they start to display below each other

how can i stop it so they will always display inline?

Comment: from a design point of view, isn't it better to have them on different lines if the window is too small instead of on one line with a huge scrollbar?

Comment: no i would rather have the scroll bar on this occasion

Answer (score 0):

There are two main ways to do it:

- The old (not to mention deprecated) `<nobr>` tag. Just put everything you want on one line inside of this tag
- Put all of the buttons into a `<div>`, then add this css property to it: `white-space: nowrap;`

You should probably use the latter